# WSDL and XSD file reference update

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I am exposing multiple SOAP based web services to my clients. Often times, I get requirements asking for additional fields to be included in response or modify existing fields which are already part of the web response.

The situation here is not all of my clients are interested in the new fields and they prefer not to update the WSDL and XSD references in their application unless it is required to be done to avoid errors during serialization and deserialization.

The question is when should someone be forced to refresh the WSDL and XSD references in order to avoid errors while invoking webservices ? While introducing new fields or modifying existing fields or in both situations ?

Comment: You can find your answer [do-i-need-to-update-wcf-service-references-when-making-an-agument-optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718399/do-i-need-to-update-wcf-service-references-when-making-an-agument-optional)

Comment: So did it work?